# Bypass ISP DNS hijacking with OpenWRT DNSMasq

Tags: networking, router, dns, dd-wrt, openwrt

So my ISP is blocking some site left and right, changing the DNS manually is not working due to Transparent DNS Proxy. The workaround is possible by installing DNSCrypt in my computer, however not every PC support DNSCrypt.

I was thinking to fix this problem on router level so every device under the router would be able to access every site without additional program like DNSCrypt.

I can do this on DD-WRT with :

[image]
[image]

I already read this page but still confused https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dhcp.dnsmasq

Can someone guide me for equivalent settings on OpenWRT?

Comment: **however not every PC support DNSCrypt** - What makes you think this?  What does `DNSMasq` have to do with `DNSCrypt`?  They two are not actually related.  One is a DNS forwarder which supports `DNSSEC` the other is `DNSCrypt` which is something else entirely.

Comment: I don't know much about networking but as far as I know, the ISP is hijacking port 53. DNSMasq or DNSCrypt can redirect this to another port to for example 443 or 5353.

Comment: I was just raising a question.  I am not sure the reason, you even talk about DNSCrypt, since your not even interested in using it.  The article you linked to, describes how you enable it, all you have to do SSH into the router and edit those files.  [Of course per the article you linked to, DNSMasq, is configured already.](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp)